# How can I get the data from an outlook email account, such as emails, contacts, and calendar events, and show it inside a list?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a user control (WPF) and put it inside a `TabControl`. That's fine, but I want to get the data, like an email or a contact, and put it in that user control as part of a list and show it in a list box, something like this:

[image]

In the email tab, show emails,
In the contacts tab, show contacts,
In the Events tab, show Calendar events,
All in the same fashion.

Comment: Have you tried implementing [DataTemplate](https://www.wpftutorial.net/ListBoxDataTemplate.html) ?

Comment: @dhilmathy Thank you I will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage the Outlook API and make the appropriate calls. Microsoft has documentation on it.

Format your response into a collection of custom objects that are mapped, and then iterate through that collection to generate and populate your elements.

Outlook API starting point:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started

Comment: I will check it out but after I get them, how can I put it a pane like in the image in my question?

Answer (score 0):

To get contacts, emails and events from out look, you can use Microsoft Graph API. you can check those thing on documentation of this [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).